# How do I get image data using an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 and jQuery, and I need to display a table with two columns; The first column should contain the image of a person and the second, the details of that person.

I'm getting the person's details and the image path from the database via an AJAX call, and display my table. But instead of the image being shown, I am getting path only.

How can I get the image using an AJAX call, so I can display it in my table? My controller is returning JSON data.

Comment: What about placing that path into the `src` property of an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can put image path in  tag "src"  attribute using javascript.